# PostgreSQL Slow query, Order by LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-9.4

- List item

`mydbab=# \d+ table1;`

```
                   Table "dbmydb.table1"
     Column     |  Type   | Modifiers | Scol5rage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------
 pk             | bigint  | not null  | plain      |              |   
 col1           | bigint  | not null  | plain      |              |   
 col2           | citext  | not null  | extended   |              |   
 col3           | citext  |           | extended   |              |        
 col4           | citext  | not null  | extended   |              |   
 col5           | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 col6           | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 bcol7          | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 col8           | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 col9           | citext  |           | extended   |              |  
 col10          | bigint  | not null  | plain      |              |   
 col11          | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 col12          | bigint  |           | plain      |              |     
 col13          | integer | default 1 | plain      |              |   
 col14          | integer | default 0 | plain      |              |   
 col15          | bigint  |           | plain      |              |   
 col16          | integer | default 0 | plain      |              |   
 col17          | integer | default 0 | plain      |              |     
 col18          | integer | default 0 | plain      |              |   
 col19          | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 col20          | citext  |           | extended   |              |   
 col21          | citext  |           | extended   |              |
```

Indexes:

```
"table1_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pk)  
"table1_idx3" btree (col10)  
"table1_idx4" btree ("col4")  
"table1_idx5" btree (col11)  
"table1_idx6" btree (col15)  
"table1_fk_idx" btree (col1)
```

Check constraints:

```
"table1_col6_c" CHECK (length(col6::text) <= 5000)
"table1_col4_c" CHECK (length("col4"::text) <= 253)
"table1_col5_c” CHECK (length(col5::text) <= 5000)
"table1_col3_c" CHECK (length(col3::text) <= 253)
"table1_col11_c" CHECK (length(col11::text) <= 253)
"table1_col20_c” CHECK (length(col20::text) <= 200)
"table1_col21_c” CHECK (length(col21::text) <= 500)
"table1_col7_c” CHECK (length(col7::text) <= 500)
"table1_col9_c" CHECK (length(col9::text) <= 100)
"table1_col5_c" CHECK (length("col5"::text) <= 5000)
"table1_col19_c” CHECK (length(col19::text) <= 100)
```

Foreign-key constraints:

```
"table1_fk" FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES table2(col1) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Referenced by:

```
TABLE “table3” CONSTRAINT “table3_fk2" FOREIGN KEY (pk) REFERENCES table1(pk) ON DELETE CASCADE  
TABLE “table4” CONSTRAINT “table4_fk2" FOREIGN KEY (pk) REFERENCES table1(pk) ON DELETE CASCADE  
TABLE “table5” CONSTRAINT “table5_fk1" FOREIGN KEY (pk) REFERENCES table1(pk)  
TABLE “table6” CONSTRAINT “table6_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pk) REFERENCES table1(pk) ON DELETE CASCADE  
TABLE “table7” CONSTRAINT “table7_fk1" FOREIGN KEY (pk) REFERENCES table1(pk) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Options: `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05`

**QUERY PLAN**

```sql
explain SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ((table1.col1 = 814000000002054) AND (((table1.pk >= 238000000000000) AND (table1.pk <= 238999999999999)) OR  ((table1.pk >= 0) AND (table1.pk <= 999999999999))))   ORDER BY table1.col15 DESC LIMIT 7
```

```
(query gets timed out for explain analyze) 

Limit (cost=0.56..607.64 rows=7 width=603)

Index Scan Backward using table1_idx6 on table1 (cost=0.56..12622561.13 rows=145548 width=603) Filter: ((col1 = 814000000002054::bigint) AND (((pk >= 238000000000000::bigint) AND (pk <= 238999999999999::bigint)) OR ((pk >= 0) AND (pk <= 999999999999::bigint))))
```

***Problem:
Table has got 50M records.
This query is taking more than 15minutes to run! We have calibrated to auto vacuum to 0.05. Auto analyse is in its PG’s default.
the query was even changed to ORDER BY table1.col15 ASC LIMIT 7, even the the query is taking around the same time.
Insert/Update operation takes only ms.***

History: The result used to be faster when it has lesser data -
Query had no issues in MySQL, migrated to Pg few weeks back.

Worker_mem is 956MB.

`select version();`

```
 PostgreSQL 9.4.0 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Comment: How many records (% of total) fits `col1 = 814000000002054`? If less than 5-10%, it should be using index on that column.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and pare down your question to something more digestable.

Comment: @Andreas would have about 2million records in the table with col1= 814000000002054

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen am sorry, but the describe table is taking so much space.. i have formatted them now.

Comment: Assuming `pk` criterias don't filter a lot, replacing index on `col1` with an index on `col1, col15` would likely improve performance.

Comment: actually it is PK's that is filtering it out to say 3M records from 55M records (User data sharding done on PK).

Answer (score 0):

Try create a multiple-column index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table1(col15, col1, pk);
```

Comment: if you could please explain on how it will improve ? (user data sharding on PK fyi) and moreover it is not that the query is not efficient here i suppose.